# Joining results of two mySQL queries

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mySQL queries. Individually, they give me what I'm looking for. However, I prefer to combine the results into a single set.

First query. Simple selection from table 'profile'.

```
SELECT id, first, last, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, NOW()) AS age 
FROM profile WHERE active = 'Y'
```

Results:

```
|id               |first    | last | age|
|160808213759VYO  |Peter    |Pan   | 31 |
|160808214828NGO  |Lion     |King  | 30 |
|160808215315TRA  |Buck     |Roger | 29 |
```

Second query. For a given `id` there are multiple entries (description). I
want to pick out the first entry for a given `id` only and it's working correctly.

```
SELECT r.id, (SELECT r1.description FROM reference r1 
WHERE r1.id = r.id AND r1.active = 'Y' ORDER BY r1.description ASC LIMIT 1) 
AS image 
FROM reference r WHERE r.type = 'I' AND r.active = 'Y' 
GROUP BY r.id 
ORDER BY r.id, image;
```

Result:

```
|id             |image                         |
|160808213759VYO|   img/160808213759VYO_003.jpg|
|160808214828NGO|   img/160808214828NGO_002.jpg|
|160808215315TRA|   img/160808215315TRA_001.jpg|
```

How can I join these two queries to get this:

```
|id             |first   |  last |  age|   image                       |
|160808213759VYO|   Peter|  Pan  |  31 |   img/160808213759VYO_003.jpg |
|160808214828NGO|   Lion |  King |  30 |   img/160808214828NGO_002.jpg |
|160808215315TRA|   Buck |  Roger|  29 |   img/160808215315TRA_001.jpg |
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure something like:

```
SELECT p.id, p.first, p.last, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, NOW()) AS age
     , MIN(r.description) as image 
FROM profile p
JOIN reference r 
    ON r.id = p.id
WHERE r.type = 'I' AND r.active = 'Y' 
  AND p.active = 'Y'
GROUP BY p.id, p.first, p.last, p.dob
```

;

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID
     , A.FIRST
     , A.LAST
     , A.AGE
     , B.IMAGE
FROM (SELECT id
           , first
           , last
           , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, NOW()) AS age 
      FROM profile 
      WHERE active = 'Y' ) A
JOIN (SELECT r.id
             , (SELECT r1.description 
                FROM reference r1 
                WHERE r1.id = r.id 
                AND r1.active = 'Y' 
                ORDER BY r1.description ASC 
                LIMIT 1) AS image 
       FROM reference r 
       WHERE r.type = 'I'
         AND r.active = 'Y' 
       GROUP BY r.id 
       ORDER BY r.id, image) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```